# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 35 boolean expression

Tags: python

I am wondering how the lines

```
elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
    print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
    bear_moved = True
```

... and ...

```
elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
    dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
```

... implement the variable `bear_moved`? It is already defined as `False` before the `while` loop, and I am wondering why it is compared to what is entered in "choice" and how it checks it when you are just typing your answer. Also, if it says "`not`" `bear_moved`, doesn't that make the variable true? Then why is it defined as true under it?

```
def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif choice == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."
```

Comment: I'm really beginning to hate this book, and especially this exercise. The Related list shows how many people don't understand this code because the book hasn't explained it properly. And that `gold_room()` line (notice there's no `return` there…) leads to hundreds of people sequencing functions this way and having dups of the various problems that causes…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bear_moved` is not compared with `choice`. It is tested for boolean truth *only if `choice == "taunt bear"` is true*.

The test `if bear_moved:` *on its own* is true or false based entirely on the value of `bear_moved`. So if `bear_moved = False`, then the test `if bear_moved:` is going to fail. IF `bear_moved = True`, then `if bear_moved:` is going to succeed:

```
>>> bear_moved = False
>>> if bear_moved:
...     print('The bear moved')
... 
>>> bear_moved = True
>>> if bear_moved:
...     print('The bear moved')
... 
The bear moved
```

`not` inverts the test; now when you set it as `bear_moved = False`, `if not bear_moved:` is going to succeed, and vice versa:

```
>>> bear_moved = False
>>> if not bear_moved:
...     print('The bear has not moved')
... 
The bear has not moved
>>> bear_moved = True
>>> if not bear_moved:
...     print('The bear has not moved')
... 
>>>
```

Coming back to `choice`, the test first looks at `choice == "taunt bear"`. If that is true, only *then* does `and` also test `bear_moved`. So for `if choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:` to succeed, two things must be true: `choice` must be set to `"taunt bear"` *and* the value of `bear_moved` must be true.

In the `while` loop, the first time around, `bear_moved` is set to `False`. If you pick `taunt bear`, the test `elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:` is going to be true: `choice == "taunt bear"` is true, *and* `not bear_moved` is true because `bear_moved` is `False`. A message is printed and `bear_moved` is now changed to `True`.

The `while` loop continues, and you can pick `"taunt bear"` again, but this time `bear_moved` is set to `True`. The test `elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:` is not going to succeed, because even though `choice == "taunt bear"` is true, the `not bear_moved` part is not true! However, the other test, `elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:` is true now, and thus you die.

Incidentally, the moment `bear_moved = True` has been executed, the `elif choice = "open door" and bear_moved:` test becomes available, provided you used `"open door"` as a choice of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the evaluation or the comparison operators here.

```
elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
```

what this statement says is the following:

```
if choice is the text "taunt bear"
and
the boolean variable bear_moved is False
```

it is also not changing bear_moved; it's just checking whether it's False.

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through it.

When you start the loop, `bear_moved` is `False`, because of that `bear_moved = False` line.

So, it asks you for a choice, you type `taunt bear`, and it gets to that line:

```
    elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
```

Obviously `choice == "taunt bear"`, since that's what you typed.

As for `not bear_moved`, that doesn't modify `bear_moved`, it just means "use the opposite of whatever is in `bear_moved`". So, since `bear_moved` is `False`, that means `not bear_moved` is `True`.

And since both sides of the `and` are `True`, the whole thing is `True`. So, it prints out the message, and sets `bear_moved = True`.

Now, the next time you go through the loop, you type `taunt bear` again, and it gets to the same line.

This time, because you set `bear_moved = True`, `bear_moved` is now `True`, so `not bear_moved` is now `False`. Since one side of the `and` is `False`, the whole thing is `False`, so it skips this line and goes to the next one.

In the next test, `choice == "taunt bear"` is still `True`, and `bear_moved` is also `True`, so now you die.

Comment: What would happen if you were to use "or" instead, since one of them would be true choice would be true, wouldn't it? What is the point of doing the double bear_moved line?

Comment: @user3099345: If you used `or`, then yes, every time you typed `taunt bear` it would execute this code, whether `bear_moved` were true or false—and, not only that, after you executed it the first time, `bear_moved` would be true, so every time you typed _anything_ except `take honey`, it would execute this code. So you'd never be able to get to the `The bear gets pissed off` case, or the `gold_room` case. You'd just be stuck in this room forever.

Comment: @user3099345: As for your second question, I don't kno wwhat you mean by "the double bear_moved line".